# MX MASTER 3 (for Mac) not recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I recently purchased a MX Master 3 Logitech mouse and I was hoping to use it on my Desktop computer with Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, my computer does not seem to recognize the device (I have a quite recent motherboard with Bluetooth included (MSI MAG B550M MORTAR WIFI DDR4 mATX Motherboard)).

The Bluetooth works fine, I can connect my headphones and even my airpods, but the mouse is not seen among the devices. I have no idea why at what can I do to use the mouse. Any help?

I realized that the version that I bought is for Mac, but I managed to use the mouse also on a pixelbook without any issue. I guess that the "for Mac" version should not impact its usage with Ubuntu...

Comment: I wish I could give you an actual answer but I'll just say that I feel your pain. My MX Master has been a disaster on Ubuntu 20.04.  It works just fine on Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint.  But on Ubuntu 20.04, scrolling is a circus.  If I open the `Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Test Your Settings`, scroll does nothing.  If I scroll in Thunderbird, it will scroll through the accounts pane but not the email listing.  `xev` does not recognize buttons 4 and 5.  I could go on and on.  I'm thinking of downgrading to 18.04.

Comment: The issue that I think I am facing is that the Mac version does not come with a receiver, which makes the mouse invisible to Ubuntu (don't ask me why, I could not figure it out - my pixelbook was able to see it and connect to it). I had to return it and buy one with the bluetooth receiver... Really sad about it..